# How to group this report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I want to know if there is a way to group this report. This is my report.

[image]

This report is grouped by two columns "Merchant" and "ConfirmationID" and ordered by the columns "date" and "time". As you can see the Merchant is repeated twice because of the groupings. I want to know if there a way to group this column "Merchant" to show in this way:

[image]

I tried to add one more parent group with the column merchant but the output is different that I want because it groups all together and don't respect the sort of the columns time and date. This is the result if I add a parent group with the column Merchant:

[image]

If anyone can help me I would appreciate too much.

Comment: You said the report is ordered by date and time but the images do not appear to be ordered like this. Also, the problem would be easier for others to help with if you can provide a script to produce your sample data to work from.

Comment: From the data you show : I would have a first group for the Merchant > Child group ConfirmationID. In the child group I would set the grouping on Confirmation ID and the Sorting on Date then Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially group on confirmation id (1st group) and then on merchant (2nd group).

Create two rows for your merchant group.

On the first row put the merchant field and on the second the column headers.

You need to hide these two rows when merchant value doesn't change.
In order to do this set the row visibility expression to  `=(Fields!merchant.Value = Previous(First(Fields!merchant.Value,"merchant")))`

Order your detail by date and time.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE for totals**

Create only one group

Add the following custom code to your report

```
Dim current_merchant
Dim current_confirmation

Public Function CustomGroup( merchant As String, confirmation As Integer) As String

If current_merchant <> merchant Then
    current_merchant = merchant
    current_confirmation = confirmation
End If

Return current_merchant & " " & Cstr(current_confirmation)

End Function
```

For your group set the expression to `=Code.CustomGroup(Fields!merchant.Value, Fields!confirmation_id.Value)`

Set the detail sorting on confirmation_id, date, time
You don't need any visibility expressions

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes it works! But just in case do you know how can I add subtotals in the end of each merchant?

Comment: Because this is a workaround, subtotals may not work the way you expect because of the grouping on confirmation_id. Please update the question or create a new one, providing the full layout design with the subtotals

Comment: Check again and see if you are ok with the subtotals